# Активировать PUT DELETE методы в WebAPI ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Имею контроллер

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("[action]/")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        return Ok(await _employeeService.GetAllEmployees());
    }
    [HttpDelete("[action]/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        await _employeeService.DeleteEmployee(id);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Через Swagger всё замечательно работает, все запросы выполняются. А вот если ввести строку запроса напрямую, в моём случае: https://localhost:7080/Employee/Delete/3, то возвращает 405. Почитал в инете, встретил похожую ситуацию, только уже с задеплоиными API, а у меня даже на локал хосте не работает. Что мог упустить?

Вызываю в TypeScript вот таким вот образом:

```
async function deleteById(url: string, id: number) {
    return await fetch(url + id.toString(), { method: 'DELETE', }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok)
            console.log(response);
        else
            return response.json();
    });
}
deleteById("https://localhost:7080/Employee/Delete/", id).then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
    });
```

И получаю вот такое...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что DELETE запрос нельзя выполнить через адресную строку, т.к браузер не понимает какой это HTTP запрос(post, put, delete). Это мои догадки, не уверен, что прав.

Comment: `А вот если ввести строку запроса напрямую` - куда? В браузер? Так при отправке любого запроса в браузере - отправляется `GET` запрос, а у вас `DELETE`, такие запросы только программно отправить можно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, понял, через браузер напрямую нельзя. Имею так же локально фронт на другом порте, отправляю запрос от-туда прилетает так же 405 CORS

Comment: Как отправляете? Отловить пробовали то, что отправляете? В C#, например для отправки запросов есть `HttpClient`, а у него методы, например для Delete это `DeleteAsync();`.

Comment: Через TypeScript, метод fetch, пробовал обычно передавать запрос, и с параметром `method: "DELETE"`

Comment: Как в JS и прочем отсылать запросы - не скажу, но даже на скрине видно ведь, что у вас шлется GET запрос, а не DELETE. Так что, с методом отправки явно что-то не то. Главное сама суть проблемы: Во всех случаях вы посылаете GET запрос, а не DELETE, вам и идет в ответ 405 - такого метода нет.